# Android Wear Watch Face: onDraw() alternative in WatchFaceService?

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

as explained here (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html) to draw a watch face I have to use the method OnDraw, is that right? there are no alternatives?

is this a joke? no layout from xml management? no dpi management? no screen format management? etc etc?

really?

Please tell me I'm wrong!

PS this page (http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/how-to-create-a-custom-android-wear-watch-face/120) make a watch face using a normal activity, it's correct or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In onCreateEngine() of your WatchFaceService, get the inflater:

```
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

then in onCreate() of your Engine, inflate your layout:

```
mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

then in onDraw(), measure, layout and draw the view:

```
        //Measure the view at the exact dimensions (otherwise the text won't center correctly)
        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(bounds.width(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(bounds.height(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        mFrameLayout.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);

        //Lay the view out at the rect width and height
        mFrameLayout.layout(0, 0, bounds.width(), bounds.height());

        mFrameLayout.draw(canvas);
```

Just don't expect to do this with a TextClock.  It doesn't exist on Android Wear.  Apparently, Google didn't anticipate developers would want to display a clock on the watchface!

Comment: seems necessary to add this at the beginning:
canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you have to use a Canvas or OpenGL. 
The link you gave explained an old workaround working for pre 5.0 version.
Now, you have to use the new API.

Comment: it's crazy! when in a few years there will be devices with different resolutions?

Comment: I can't see any problem. The API gives you all the information needed to display your watchface correctly.

Comment: yes, but i need to do all programmatically! Welcome in the 90.

Comment: @Xan what's the big deal in that you have to draw your watch face with Canvas API? CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine is like a WallpaperService.Engine and in wallpaper API you don't have any "managements" you mentioned in your original question

Comment: never done a WallpaperService. I am very surprised by this, the strength of Android is an SDK that lets you easily create interfaces that fit on all screens (Density and Size). I do not understand the reason for this choice. save battery?

Comment: you can still use xml layouts: `v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.xxxx, null)` then you can call `v.measure()` and `v.layout()` and finally `v.draw()` in `onDraw()` method